# Corresponding sums of list data

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simulation with R about a sequence of 0,1’s of length 1000 for 500 times. And trying to figure out the average steps of 3 consecutive ones. This is actually the same as finding the expectation number of times a coin is tossed and comes up heads three times in a row. The rle stands for run length encoding function, which takes a sequence and converts it into running sequence of consecutive elements.

```
uu<-matrix(sample(c(0,1),500000,replace = TRUE,prob = c(1/2,1/2)),ncol = 1000)
yy<-apply(uu,1,rle)
f1<-function(yy){
  which(yy$lengths>2&yy$values==1)
}
tt<-sapply(yy,f1)
oo<-sapply(tt, function(tt) return(tt[1]))
```

After I got the first element of tt which means the first sequence of 3 consecutive heads. And I want to cumsum or sum the previous throw I made before the first 3 consecutive heads.
And I don't know how to do it 500 times and correspondingly.

```
f2<-function(yy){sum(yy$length[1:oo[1:500]])+3}
kk<-sapply(yy,f2)
mean(kk)
```

However, the f2 won't work since R only captures the first element of oo. I am wondering how to sum the corresponding element of yy$length and oo? Please tell me if there is there more convenient way to do this simulation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code can certainly be simplified, but I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Start with 1 run of 50 and show us what you want to compute: `set.seed(42)`, then `x <- sample(0:1, 50, replace=TRUE)` then `x.rle <- rle(x)` and finally `which(x.rle$lengths > 2 & x.rle$values == 1)`. Now the result is 2, 10, 14, 18, 20. Show us what are you trying to compute from these values? After we get the code for one sample, we can easily expand it to many samples with `replicate()`.

Comment: @Yukun Liang - What do you mean by _steps of 3 consecutive ones_? And _R only captures the first element of oo_? - You only capture the first elements of tt into oo.

Comment: This is actually the same as finding the expectation number of times a coin is tossed and comes up heads three times in a row. The result of ```which(x.rle$lengths > 2 & x.rle$values == 1)```is to find the corresponding sequence of the simulation when the value is 1 and I only need the first number(the first time in this that got a 3 consecutive heads). So I extracted the first element from tt which is oo. And then I need to sum them up. Just like```sum(yy$length[1]:oo[1])``` and do it for 500 times. This can help me get the times I need to have three times in a row for 500 times.

Comment: Are you looking for _exactly_ 3 consecutive heads, e.g. `0 1 1 1 0`, or _at least_ 3 consecutive heads, e.g., `0 1 1 1 1 1 0`?

Comment: I am looking for the first sequence of exactly 3 consecutive heads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to simulate how many throws it takes on average until exactly 3 heads occur consecutively.

Here is an example how this can be solved using `replicate()`:

```
nt <- 20L # number of throws in a sequence
nr <- 10L # number of repetitions
set.seed(42) # for reproducible results
mean(
  replicate(
    nr, { 
      throws <- sample(0:1, nt, replace = TRUE)
      print(throws)
      throws_rle <- rle(throws)
      rle_len <- throws_rle[["lengths"]]
      rle_val <- throws_rle[["values"]]
      idx_first_3_heads <- head(which(rle_val == 1L & rle_len == 3L), 1L)
      # add lengths of previous throws
      n_previous_throws <- if (length(idx_first_3_heads) > 0) 
      {
        sum(head(rle_len, idx_first_3_heads - 1L))
      } else {
        NA
      }
      cat("First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after", n_previous_throws, "throws\n")
      n_previous_throws
    }
  ),
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

> ```
>  [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after NA throws
>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after 17 throws
>  [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after NA throws
>  [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after NA throws
>  [1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after 13 throws
>  [1] 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after NA throws
>  [1] 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after 14 throws
>  [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after 9 throws
>  [1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after 17 throws
>  [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
> First occurrence of exactly 3 heads after 0 throws
> [1] 11.66667
> ```

Note that this code hopefully is self-explaining and is just for demonstration. It will need to be streamlined for production use.

The `if` clause is required to distinguish between the situation

- where no 3 consecutive heads occur at all in a sequence (returns `NA`)
- and where the 3 consecutive heads occur right at the start (returns 0 as there are no previous throws).

Both situations can be found in the sample use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I was trying to find at least 3 consecutive heads(I'm sorry I gave you the wrong information), it can adapt to that by changing some parameters. This code is awesome and very helpful to me. And I have figured out this with apply function. I will post my answer later. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, build up a sequence of 0,1's of length 1000 for 500 times.

```
A<-matrix(sample(c(0,1),1000000,replace=TRUE),ncol=1000)
```

Second, using a function to find the sequence of the first occurrence of 3 consecutive ones and sum it together. Since`sum(rle(x)$lengths[1:BB[1]-1])`only give us the number before 3 consecutive ones, it need more 3 steps to get the answer. So there is a +3 after sum.

```
AA<-function(x,y){
  BB<-which(rle(x)$lengths>2&rle(x)$values==y)
  if(length(BB)==0)
    return(0)
  sum(rle(x)$lengths[1:BB[1]-1])+3
}
```

Apply this function to the original matrix.

```
CC<-apply(A,1,AA,y=1)
```

By calculating the mean of CC, we can get the answer of average steps to get 3 consecutive ones through this simulation.

```
mean(CC)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this meant as a self-answer or to provide more information for your question? In the first case, code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. In the second case, please use the edit link to edit your question instead of adding a non-answer in the answers section.